# npm install using service connection failed with code 404

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm having issues getting service connections to install packages from my organization.
Here's my project setup:

Project 1 (Internals)

- Artifact Feed Project Scoped (InternalsArtifacts) - Has @local, @prerelease, and @release packages.

  - @internals/express-common@0.6.0

Project 2 (Alpha)

- Pipeline

  - Validation.yml

```
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '13.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'
  
  - task: npmAuthenticate@0
    inputs:
      workingFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.npmrc'
      customEndpoint: 'InternalsArtifacts-Alpha' # This is a shared service connection from Internals

  - task: Npm@1
    inputs:
      command: 'install'
    displayName: 'npm install'
```

- Code: ./npmrc

```
@scope:registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{org}/Internals/_packaging/internals/npm/registry/

always-auth=true
```

I *know* that the artifact is there. The url it produces that claims 404 actually works when authenticated to download the package. Something has to be wrong in the pipeline's authentication handling to reach through the service connector. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Based on my test, it may cause 404  in many cases. You could refer to the answer to change the settings and check if it could work. Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help.

Comment: Reviewing now. Thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> npm install using service connection failed with code 404

I could reproduce this issue. A project-scoped feed within Project1, your Project2's pipeline can't find the package from feed1 by default. It's by design behavior.

You could try the following steps to solve this issue:

1.Check if the package version in `package.json file` exists in the feed.

2.Go `Organization Settings ->Settings` to disable  `Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines` option. (Pipelines can run with collection scoped access tokens unless this option is enabled. With this option enabled, you can reduce the scope of access for all pipelines to the current project.)

3.Then in Project2: Go `Project Settings ->Settings` and disable  `Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines` option. So that Project2's pipeline can access project1's feed with collection scoped access token.

4.Run the Project2's pipeline again, if the issue persists. Then check feed1's feed settings:

Add `Project2 Build Service(Org)` as `Contributor` role in Permissions.

Or you could add the `Project2 Build Service(Org)`  as a member of project team in `Project Settings-> Teams` in Project 1.

[image]

Or

[image]

Comment: 1. Yes, the item exists as the dev team can install it.

2. Limit job authorization scope - All are disabled.

3. Project specific - Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines - This was the culprit.

I didn't see that there was a project specific restriction in the docs aside from the organizational. Thank you!